# How to allocate (malloc) memory in an angr simulation state?

Tags: python-3.x, x86-64, reverse-engineering, elf, angr

I successfully figured out how to run a program using angr, starting with the state defined by a core dump (see [How to run program using angr after loading with the elfcore backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983441/how-to-run-program-using-angr-after-loading-with-the-elfcore-backend)) but now I am wondering this:

**How can I malloc memory in the program's SimulationState?**

The starting state I am running the program from is the beginning of a function which takes a pointer and a length. I want to be able to malloc memory fresh with arbitrary lengths, and pass this pointer (and the appropriate length) instead into the function.

I found that there is what I believe is a plugin class, `angr.state_plugins.heap.heap_libc.SimHeapLibc` ([documentation](http://angr.io/api-doc/angr.html?highlight=cfg#angr.state_plugins.heap.heap_libc.SimHeapLibc)) which has a `malloc` method, but how do I use this plugin, and is it in fact what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, figured it out.

First of all, the plugin class that you want is `angr.state_plugins.heap.heap_ptmalloc.SimHeapPTMalloc`. Turns out `angr.state_plugins.heap.heap_libc.SimHeapLibc` is just the base class.

The use case then becomes:

```
simstate = angr.factory.AngrObjectFactory(proj).blank_state()

# IMPORTANT NOTE: you need to register the plugin with the name heap or it will break
simstate.register_plugin("heap", angr.state_plugins.heap.heap_ptmalloc.SimHeapPTMalloc())

# Voila, malloc and use arbitrary amounts of memory in the simulation space.
ptr = self.simstate.heap.malloc(data_len)
simstate.memory.store(ptr, simstate.solver.BVV(data_bytes, data_len*8))
```